# how would you Persist the data between multiple Activities in android without using Bundle or sharedPreferences and db also?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

activity a - > . activity b -> activity c

How would you persist the data between activities without using bundle or sharedPreferences and also db?

Comment: Global variables are an option but not recommended.

Comment: Shared viewmodel

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier shared viewmodel between activities, you mean ? how will it be helpful in terms of lifecycleobserver

Comment: @Dportology global variables at application level? could you explain it more ?

Comment: Correct. Read up on it in the docs, it is explained really well.